# gpg command line in c# compiled as a service , does not work

Tags: c#, gnupg

Coding is in C#, using Visual Studio 2019.If I replace the scommandline with a copy command, whole process works...so y does the gpg command not work?.If i paste it in a command prompt, it works.
Hope sm1 can help

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
System.Diagnostics.Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

string sCommandLine = @"gpg --batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase ******************** -- 
  output D:\extract_CES_SAE_v3_p0002031crfc_20201008205801.txt --decrypt 
    D:\extract_CES_SAE_v3_p0002031crfc_20201008205801.txt.pgp" ;

try
{
     process.StandardInput.WriteLine(sCommandLine);
     process.StandardInput.Flush();
     process.StandardInput.Close();
     process.WaitForExit();
     process.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the output you get when you execute the code? Also, what is the content in the `StandardError`, do you have any output in there?

Comment: No errors....when i create the project as a windows application and execute...all works fine...

Comment: So you don't get any output from either `StandardOutput` nor `StandardError`?

Comment: Nope...so at first, i tested if cmd.exe works...so sent a simple copy file as request and that works.

Comment: As you have a `try` block, what are you doing in the `catch` block? Do you get any exceptions and if so, what is the exception message?

Comment: Why do you use `cmd.exe` and not use the `gpg.exe` binary directly in your `Process.Start()` call?

Comment: No error message in Try Block.I will try use ther gpg.exe directly and revert back with results.